# Implementation of a throttled ConcurrentQueue Rx observer

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I was looking for a solution to allow me to rate limit the number of outgoing REST calls but preserved the order of queued elements so I found a [rate limiter implementation](http://www.pennedobjects.com/2010/10/better-rate-limiting-with-dot-net/) and combined it with `ConcurrentQueue<T>`.

Improvements/critique?

**Version 2 after assimilating svick's comments and adding a Unit Test**

Throttle class is the renamed version of RateGate

```
public static class BlockingCollectionExtensions
{
    // TODO: devise a way to avoid problems if collection gets too big (produced faster than consumed)
    public static IObservable<T> AsRateLimitedObservable<T>(this BlockingCollection<T> sequence, int items, TimeSpan timePeriod, CancellationToken producerToken)
    {
        Subject<T> subject = new Subject<T>();

        // this is a dummyToken just so we can recreate the TokenSource
        // which we will pass the proxy class so it can cancel the task
        // on disposal
        CancellationToken dummyToken = new CancellationToken();
        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(producerToken, dummyToken);

        var consumingTask = new Task(() =>
        {
            using (var throttle = new Throttle(items, timePeriod))
            {
                while (!sequence.IsCompleted)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        T item = sequence.Take(producerToken);
                        throttle.WaitToProceed();
                        try
                        {
                            subject.OnNext(item);
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            subject.OnError(ex);
                        }
                    }
                    catch (OperationCanceledException)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                subject.OnCompleted();
            }
        }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        return new TaskAwareObservable<T>(subject, consumingTask, tokenSource);
    }

    private class TaskAwareObservable<T> : IObservable<T>, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Task task;
        private readonly Subject<T> subject;
        private readonly CancellationTokenSource taskCancellationTokenSource;

        public TaskAwareObservable(Subject<T> subject, Task task, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
        {
            this.task = task;
            this.subject = subject;
            this.taskCancellationTokenSource = tokenSource;
        }

        public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
        {
            var disposable = subject.Subscribe(observer);
            if (task.Status == TaskStatus.Created)
                task.Start();
            return disposable;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // cancel consumption and wait task to finish
            taskCancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            task.Wait();

            // dispose tokenSource and task
            taskCancellationTokenSource.Dispose();
            task.Dispose();

            // dispose subject
            subject.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Unit test:

```
class BlockCollectionExtensionsTest
{
    [Fact]
    public void AsRateLimitedObservable()
    {
        const int maxItems = 1; // fix this to 1 to ease testing
        TimeSpan during = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        // populate collection
        int[] items = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        BlockingCollection<int> collection = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        foreach (var i in items) collection.Add(i);
        collection.CompleteAdding();

        IObservable<int> observable = collection.AsRateLimitedObservable(maxItems, during, CancellationToken.None);
        BlockingCollection<int> processedItems = new BlockingCollection<int>();
        ManualResetEvent completed = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        DateTime last = DateTime.UtcNow;
        observable
            // this is so we'll receive exceptions
            .ObserveOn(new SynchronizationContext()) 
            .Subscribe(item =>
                {
                    if (item == 1)
                        last = DateTime.UtcNow;
                    else
                    {
                        TimeSpan diff = (DateTime.UtcNow - last);
                        last = DateTime.UtcNow;

                        Assert.InRange(diff.TotalMilliseconds,
                            during.TotalMilliseconds - 30,
                            during.TotalMilliseconds + 30);
                    }
                    processedItems.Add(item);
                },
                () => completed.Set()
            );
        completed.WaitOne();
        Assert.Equal(items, processedItems, new CollectionEqualityComparer<int>());
    }
}
```

**Version 1 for reference**

```
public static class QueueExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<T> LimitRateObservable<T>(this ConcurrentQueue<T> sequence, int items, TimeSpan timePeriod, CancellationToken token)
    {
        Subject<T> subject = new Subject<T>();

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            using (var rateGate = new RateGate(items, timePeriod))
            {
                while (!token.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    // we could have added a Sleep() here if the queue is empty
                    // to avoid hammering it with Dequeue requests
                    // but the limiting itself does the work for us
                    T item;
                    if (sequence.TryDequeue(out item))
                    {
                        rateGate.WaitToProceed();
                        subject.OnNext(item);
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Stopping");
             }
             subject.OnCompleted();
        });

        return subject.AsObservable();
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        ConcurrentQueue<int> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<int>();

        int c = 0;
        var timer = new Timer(foo =>
        {
            queue.Enqueue(c++);
            Console.WriteLine("Added item " + c);
        }, null, 0, 300);

        CancellationTokenSource tokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        IObservable<int> observable = queue.LimitRateObservable(1, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), tokenSource.Token);

        using (observable.Timestamp().Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", x.Value, x.Timestamp.ToString("u"))))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to unsubscribe");
            Console.ReadKey();
            timer.Dispose();
            tokenSource.Cancel();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Disposed");

        Thread.Sleep(4000); // wait to show that the produced has finished
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, why is `BlockingCollection` lacking when it comes to order of the elements? By default, it internally uses `ConcurrentQueue`, which guarantees FIFO order.

Comment: Hm... you are correct, I messed something up in my original tests. `BlockingCollection<T>.GetConsumingEnumerable()` does return the items in order. However, an integration point with the rate limiter is still necessary and so the implementation above would stay the same (I might as well use `ConcurrentQueue<T>`). I'll edit my question to remove this comment.

Answer (score 1):

I think the worst thing in that code is what you alluded to in your comment: if the queue is empty, your code will busy-wait, which is a very bad idea. To fix that, you could use `BlockingCollection<T>` and its blocking method [`Take()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287085.aspx). And no, using `Thread.Sleep()` is not a good idea either.

Another thing is that if the rate of the producer is higher than the rate of the limiter, the memory used by your application will increase indefinitely. You should devise some way to limit that, like setting an upper bound to your `BlockingCollection<T>`.

Comment: Great idea. I've adapted the implementation and it's much cleaner. I'm having a problem where the first item I'm calling OnNext() doesn't get printed. I think it is related to the `Task` starting before returning the `Observable`. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: I think you have to `Subscribe()` to your observable before starting the timer to fix that.